# How to test value in x-for variable and change the CSS Style according to the value?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

How can I test the value of an x-for variable and then meet an IF condition to change the CSS value?

```
<template x-for="item in myForData" :key="item">
        <div id="jh-stats-neutral" class="flex items-center shadow hover:bg-indigo-100 
        hover:shadow-lg hover:rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform 
        hover:scale-102 flex flex-col justify-center px-2 py-3 mt-0 bg-white border
        border-gray-300 rounded md:mb-0"                     
          <div class="text-md">
            <p
              class="text-md font-semibold text-center text-red-600 *<% if ("item.categoria.substring(3)" == 'Rec') { %> bg-blue-200 <% } %>*"
              x-text="item.categoria"
            ></p>
            <p
              class="text-lg text-center text-red-700"
              x-text="item.total"
            ></p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </template>
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to the `class` attribute using `x-bind:class` or `:class` for short.

`x-bind:class` has special syntax that means you can pass it an object whose key is the class(es) and the value is whether the class(es) is applied.

Eg. `x-bind:class="{ 'hello': false, 'world': true }"` will add the `world` class but not `hello`.

In your case you can do the class toggling using Alpine:

`*<% if ("item.categoria.substring(3)" == 'Rec') { %> bg-blue-200 <% } %>*` turns into `class="...otherclasses" x-bind:class="{ 'bg-blue-200': item.categoria.substring(3) === 'Rec' }"`.

Your full code updated with the `x-bind:class`

```html
<template x-for="item in myForData" :key="item">
  <div id="jh-stats-neutral" class="flex items-center shadow hover:bg-indigo-100 
  hover:shadow-lg hover:rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform 
  hover:scale-102 flex flex-col justify-center px-2 py-3 mt-0 bg-white border
  border-gray-300 rounded md:mb-0"                     
    <div class="text-md">
      <p
        class="text-md font-semibold text-center text-red-600 *<% if ("item.categoria.substring(3)" == 'Rec') { %> bg-blue-200 <% } %>*"
        x-bind:class="{ 'bg-blue-200': item.categoria.substring(3) === 'Rec' }"
        x-text="item.categoria"
      ></p>
      <p
        class="text-lg text-center text-red-700"
        x-text="item.total"
      ></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Fantastic Hugo!
Your explanation open my mind to a world of possibilities... I left behind some trash in original code above, but it's my code updated:

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question - unfortunately I cannot add a comment - please provide more details - what exactly do you want to do.

First of all, x-for = "item in myForData" is not a variable but an attribute.

Comment: Hi Sylwester. I need identify  the value of each item in this case, and compare this in a IF (javascript). I need apply a class attribute depending of "item" value.

Comment: Ok, I understand each element, but about the <template> tag - is there a problem with that too? But about the value of what you mean - the value (content) of the html tag, or the value of the css attribute, or something else?

Comment: What I really need is the variable "item" value! Just this. Need read and test a condition, so, apply a specifc style depending the result found.

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic Hugo!
Your explanation open my mind to a world of possibilities... I left behind some trash in original code above, but it's my code updated:

```
      <template x-for="item in myForData" :key="item">
        <div id="jh-stats-neutral" class="flex items-center shadow hover:bg-indigo-100 
        hover:shadow-lg hover:rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform 
        hover:scale-102 flex flex-col justify-center px-2 py-3 mt-0 bg-white border
        border-gray-300 rounded md:mb-0"                     
          <div class="text-md">
            <p
              class="card text-md font-semibold text-center"
              x-bind:class="{ 'text-blue-600': item.total.substring(0,4) !== 'R$ -' , 'text-red-600': item.total.substring(0,4) === 'R$ -' }"
              x-text="item.conta"
            ></p>
            <p
              class="value text-lg text-center text-gray-700"
              x-text="item.total"
            ></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
```

Thanks once more time and let you know that I'm your fã!